# Find the volume enclosed by the surface $S := \{(x,y,z): x^2 + xy + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals

> Find the volume enclosed by the surface $$S :=  \{(x,y,z): x^2 + xy + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}.$$

My attempt was this:

I moved the tricky $xy$-term over to the r.h.s.  I now have $$x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1-xy,$$ which is a sphere of radius $\sqrt{1-xy}$.

The logical next steps would be to integrate the $1$ function, using a triple, iterated-integral, in spherical coordinates.

But the innermost integral will have an upper limit of  $\sqrt{1-xy}$, which when I expand out the $x$ and $y$, will depend on all three spherical coordinates, $r$, $\theta$, and $\phi$.

What intermediate steps can I take first?  Am I going in a completely wrong direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A surface doesn't have a volume.  Presumably what is meant is the volume of the region **enclosed by** the surface, namely $R = \{(x,y,z): x^2 + x y + y^2 + z^2 \le 1\}$.

Hint: complete the square with respect to either $x$ or $y$.  You'll find cross-sections that are disks...

Comment: Ah, sorry, bad wording - I will edit the question now.  And also use your hint.  Thanks, professor.

Comment: Hi @RobertIsrael: I now have $ (x+\frac{y}{2})^2 - \frac{y^2}{4} + z^2 = 1$ as my surface, after completing the square with respect to the variable y.  This new expression is still problematic.  Can you offer another hint?  I am guessing you're going to say make a change of variable, but the (x+y/2) term has two variables in it ...

Comment: sorry, the equation is actually: $(x+ \frac{y}{2})^2 + \frac{3y^2}{4} + z^2 = 1$ ...

Comment: Taking $y$ to be constant, this describes a disk in the $xz$ plane, centred at $x=-y/2$, $z=0$.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertIsrael.  I have the surface figured out now, but I've been trying to integrate for a long time now and am getting nowhere, unfortunately.  I am trying to use cylindrical coordinates, and letting y vary, essentially treating y as the "z" variable that we normally would encounter in easier problems.  But, there seems to be no way to know the lower and upper limits of integration in the variable, y.  The equation given cannot be solved for y.  I can't isolate the y-term.  What do you think?

Comment: my limits of integration, with the integrand = 1-function, are for the radius, r, 0 and $(1- \frac{3y^2}{4})$, 0 and $2\pi$ for theta.  I don't know the limits for the y-variable...

Comment: I feel I'm almost there...can you please offer another hint, @RobertIsrael?  I would love to stick with this method of solving the problem.  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @RobertIsrael - I am user247776 (above).  I finally got the answer!! :-)  I solved for y easily enough just now, since the radius must be positive.  That gives me an absolute value inequality on y, and I now have my upper and lower limits of integration in y.  Thanks so much for your hints!!

Answer (score 0):

The variables $x, y, z$ are coordinates, so it doesn't make sense to speak of a "sphere of radius $\sqrt{1 - x y}$".

One option is to eliminate the cross-term by making the linear change of variables,
$$x = u + v, \qquad y = -u + v;$$
substituting gives that, in these coordinates, $S$ is given by
$$u^2 + 3 v^2 + z^2 = 1.$$

Comment: Hi @Travis, is there any Jacobian factor to compute, in making the above two substitutions?  How would I go about it?  I am having trouble with letting a variable equal to two new variables...

Comment: or is this simply a relabeling, and not so much a change of variables?

Comment: ...is the Jacobian = the determinant of the matrix of partials $x_u, x_v, y_u, y_v$, @travis? Thanks,

Comment: and also...the new surface is still not a sphere, and I am having trouble with setting up the problem in spherical coordinates -- I don't know the radius, if I don't have a sphere yet...

Comment: @user247776 Yes, there is a Jacobian factor, but since the transformation is linear, the Jacobian is simply its determinant. And yes, the Jacobian (when it exists) is simply the matrix of partials. It's true you don't have a sphere, but notice that there's another (linear) change of coordinates you can make, so that in those coordinates $S$ *is* a sphere.